# What do I need to do to find the missing girl?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

After beating the Skyview Temple and returning to Skyloft, a lady approaches Link, asking if he can find Kukiel, her missing daughter. Some citizens of Skyloft say that she was last seen around the graveyard, but I haven't figured out what to do there. How do I find her?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this walkthrough](http://www.zeldauniverse.net/zelda/skyward-sword-sidequest-kukiel-is-missing/):

> If you ask the people in Skyloft, you’ll learn that Kukiel was seen
>   playing near the graveyard. If you head towards the graveyard you’ll
>   meet a woman who will tell you that one of the villagers, who is
>   considered crazy, is always talking about a demon that lives in
>   Skyloft. She’ll also tell you where to find him: Pumpkin Landing.
>
> Pumpkin Landing is another island that is southeast of Skyloft. Dash
>   off Skyloft, call your Loftwing, and head that way!
>
> Once you’re there, enter the only building on the island, the Lumpy
>   Pumpkin. You’ll find the old man inside having a drink. Speak with him
>   and you’ll learn that he saw the demon in the graveyard at night.
>   He’ll also tell you how to find the demon!
>
> Head back to Skyloft and sleep in a bed until night. Then, head to the
>   graveyard. Once you’re there, follow the instructions the old man gave
>   you:
>
> Find the gravestone closest to the large tree. This will be the
>   gravestone in the top-left corner of the graveyard. Roll into the
>   gravestone. You can roll by shaking the nunchuk while sprinting. If
>   you do this correctly, a glowing symbol will appear on the gravestone.
>   Push the gravestone. When you do, the door of a nearby storage shed
>   will open and reveal a ladder. Go down the ladder and follow the path.
>   At the end, you’ll find a house and hear a scream. When you enter the
>   house, you’ll find Kukiel and a bat-like monster who will roar loudly
>   when you enter. However, when you try to attack the monster, he will
>   cower in fear and beg you not to hurt him.
>
> The monster’s will introduce himself at Batreaux and convince you that
>   he only wishes to be friends with the people of Skyloft, but due to
>   his terrifying appearance no one – except the child Kukiel – will
>   spend time with him.
>
> Batreaux will then ask you to find Gratitude Crystals for him so that
>   he can become a human. This begins an extensive side quests that is
>   tied to all of the others.
>
> Batreaux reminds you that it is dangerous at night, so Kukiel is
>   staying at his home until morning. He promises that he will then send
>   the child home.
>
> Return to a bed and sleep until morning. Then, head to Kukiel’s home.
>   She lives in the house next to the bridge in Skyloft. Inside, you’ll
>   find Kukiel safely at home. Speak with her mother to receive five
>   Gratitude Crystals.

Comment: Ahh, I had talked to the woman but chose the incorrect dialogue choice, and therefore she didn't tell me about the man at the Pumpkin Landing.